# Cast SQL Column definition and default value

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table create definition in SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog] 
(
   [RawEvent] NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
   [ReceivedDate] AS CAST(JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.ReceivedTime') AS DATETIME)
)
```

When I receive a JSON string, that string has `ReceivedTime` which I parse out and use that as the `ReceivedDate` column's value when inserting this record.

This is currently working. However, when `RawEvent` string doesn't have the property `ReceivedTime`, I want to use the current SQL date time as the default value instead of NULL which is what it is doing now.

Is this possible to do in the table definition?

Comment: You can use an on-insert trigger on the table to overwrite a NULL value with GETDATE.

Comment: Or make a second column (maybe ReceivedDate2), default it with GETDATE(), and then have a computed column do a `CASE WHEN ReceivedDate IS NULL THEN ReceivedDate2 ELSE ReceivedDate END` or something similar. This may prove additionally useful as you will have a timestamp for the row, always.

Comment: Does `AS COALESCE(CAST(JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.ReceivedTime') AS DATETIME, GETDATE()))` work? (It should but I don't have any valid JSON to try with.)

Comment: @RussellFox I don't think a trigger can directly update a computed column.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'll test this out, if it works your solution is a great and elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL you can use COALESCE to supply a default value instead of null

```
COALESCE(CAST(JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.ReceivedTime') AS DATETIME),GETDATE())
```

Comment: ooops, I just saw that aaron had this in the comments -- I also didn't test

Answer (score 1):

While I think @AaronBertrand idea of `COALESCE` is more straightforward, here's a working example using computed columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EventLog] (
   [RawEvent]               NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
   [ReceivedDate]           AS CAST(JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.ReceivedTime') AS DATETIME),
   [ReceivedDateDefault]    DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
   [ReceivedDateCalculated] AS (CASE WHEN JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.ReceivedTime') IS NULL 
                                        THEN [ReceivedDateDefault] 
                                        ELSE JSON_VALUE(RawEvent, '$.ReceivedTime') END),
)

INSERT INTO dbo.EventLog (RawEvent)
VALUES
(   N'{"Foo":"Bar",
        "ReceivedTime":"2019-08-02"
        }'),
(   N'{"Foo":"Baz"
        }')
```

And the results:

```
SELECT ReceivedDateCalculated FROM dbo.EventLog

ReceivedDateCalculated
2019-08-02 00:00:00.000
2019-08-02 13:51:14.910
```

Might be some funky edge cases with empty strings or something, you would definitely want to consider that. There is one additional benefit of having the second date column, that you will always have a timestamp on this row (if you don't already). Which I've found tends to be pretty useful.